# How to calculate the value of any primitive , who has out of range value

Tags: java

Example

```
byte x;
x=(byte)2355;
System.out.println(x);
```

so, how can I calculate the value which will be in x;

Comment: You can't fit values in variables of a type that is too small to hold them, not without losing precision at least. Either you change the type of the variable, or (less likely) you use a lower value.

Comment: Take 2355, convert to binary, consider only the 8 right-most bits.

Comment: When converting a primitive value with higher precision to a one with lower precision, you may _lose information_, see [narrowing primitive conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#:~:text=22%20specific%20conversions%20on%20primitive%20types%20are%20called,byte%2C%20short%2C%20char%20%2C%20int%2C%20long%2C%20or%20float) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The `2355` literal value is interpreted as an `int`, which in Java is represented by the following 32 bits:

```
00000000000000000000100100110011
```

A `byte` has only 8 bits, so you lose the leading 24 bits:

```
00110011
```

Converted back to decimal, this leaves you with a value of `51`.

---

You can find the bit sizes of the various primitive data types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Also keep in mind that you need to take [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) into account when dealing with signed primitives.

Answer (score 0):

The range of the `byte` data type is -128 to 127 (inclusive). So if you want to deal with numbers outside that range then you can try casting the data type to `short`, `int` or `long`.